# XML comparision using xmlunit customizing output message

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, xmlunit

Hi I am trying to compare content of two xml files using xmlunit
Here are my input xmls

**reference.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<books>
    <book>
        <name>abc</name>
        <isbn>9971-5-0210-0</isbn>
        <author>abc</author>
        <category></category>
    </book>
    <book>
        <name>def</name>
        <isbn>9971-5-0222-0</isbn>
        <author>def</author>
    </book>
</books>
```

**compare.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <books>
        <book>
            <name>abc</name>
            <isbn>9971-5-0210-0</isbn>
            <author>abc</author>
            <category></category>
        </book>
        <book>
            <name>def</name>
            <isbn>9971-5-0222-0</isbn>
            <author>def</author>
        </book>
        <book>
            <name>ghi</name>
            <isbn>9971-5-0222-0</isbn>
            <author>test authora</author>
        </book>
    </books>
```

Here we can observe in the `compare.xml` there are 3 book nodes.

and I am printing the total differences and count as below

```
 DetailedDiff detDiff = new DetailedDiff(diff);
    List differences = detDiff.getAllDifferences();
    System.out.println("Total differences:-->"+differences.size());
    for (Object object : differences) {
        Difference difference = (Difference)object;
        System.out.println("***********************");
        System.out.println(difference);
        System.out.println("***********************");
    }
```

output:

```
**Total differences:-->4
```

---

Expected number of child nodes '5' but was '7' - comparing  at /books[1] to  at /books[1]

---

---

Expected text value '
' but was '
    ' - comparing 
 at /books[1]/text()[3] to 
     at /books[1]/text()[3]

---

---

Expected presence of child node 'null' but was 'book' - comparing  at null to  at /books[1]/book[3]

---

---

Expected presence of child node 'null' but was '#text' - comparing  at null to 
 at /books[1]/text()[4]

---

Instead is there any way so that i can consider change as only 1 (because I consider only one book node is added ignoring inner tags inside ) and also customize the output to our customized message

Answer (score 2):

The first step is to ignore element content whitespace which is going to remove the second and forth difference.

```
XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(true);
```

In order to suppress one of the other two differences you need to override the `DifferenceListener` and explicitly ignore one of them.  From what you describe you'd prefer to only see the `CHILD_NODE_NOT_FOUND` differences.

```
    detDiff.overrideDifferenceListener(new DifferenceListener() {
            @Override
            public int differenceFound(Difference difference) {
                return difference.getId() == DifferenceConstants.CHILD_NODELIST_LENGTH_ID
                    ? RETURN_IGNORE_DIFFERENCE_NODES_IDENTICAL
                    : RETURN_ACCEPT_DIFFERENCE;
            }
            @Override
            public void skippedComparison(Node control, Node test) { }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution may be to parse the xml files into java objects and comparing them later.

In this example I am not using xmlunit, it is based on [xstream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/index.html), I hope it will help you :

Book class

```
    public class Book {

        private String  name;
        private String  isbn;
        private String  author;
        private String  category;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(final String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getIsbn() {
            return isbn;
        }

        public void setIsbn(final String isbn) {
            this.isbn = isbn;
        }

        public String getAuthor() {
            return author;
        }

        public void setAuthor(final String author) {
            this.author = author;
        }

        public String getCategory() {
            return category;
        }

        public void setCategory(final String category) {
            this.category = category;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + (author == null ? 0 : author.hashCode());
            result = prime * result + (category == null ? 0 : category.hashCode());
            result = prime * result + (isbn == null ? 0 : isbn.hashCode());
            result = prime * result + (name == null ? 0 : name.hashCode());
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
            if (this == obj) {
                return true;
            }
            if (obj == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
                return false;
            }
            final Book other = (Book) obj;
            if (author == null) {
                if (other.author != null) {
                    return false;
                }
            } else if (!author.equals(other.author)) {
                return false;
            }
            if (category == null) {
                if (other.category != null) {
                    return false;
                }
            } else if (!category.equals(other.category)) {
                return false;
            }
            if (isbn == null) {
                if (other.isbn != null) {
                    return false;
                }
            } else if (!isbn.equals(other.isbn)) {
                return false;
            }
            if (name == null) {
                if (other.name != null) {
                    return false;
                }
            } else if (!name.equals(other.name)) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Book [name=" + name + ", isbn=" + isbn + ", author=" + author + ", category=" + category + "]";
        }

    }
```

Boks class (with main method):

```
    public class Books {

        private final List<Book>    books;

        public Books() {
            books = new ArrayList<Book>();
        }

        public void add(final Book b) {
            books.add(b);
        }

        public List<Book> getBooks() {
            return books;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return books.toString();
        }

        public static void main(final String[] args) {
            final XStream xstream = new XStream();
            xstream.alias("books", Books.class);
            xstream.alias("book", Book.class);
            xstream.addImplicitCollection(Books.class, "books");
            final Books ref = (Books) xstream.fromXML(Book.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("reference.xml"));
            final Books compare = (Books) xstream.fromXML(Book.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("compare.xml"));
            System.out.println(ref);
            System.out.println(compare);
            final List<Book> rbooks = new ArrayList<Book>(ref.getBooks());
            final List<Book> cbooks = new ArrayList<Book>(compare.getBooks());
            rbooks.removeAll(cbooks);
            System.out.println("Missing books in compare : " + rbooks);
            rbooks.clear();
            rbooks.addAll(ref.getBooks());
            cbooks.removeAll(rbooks);
            System.out.println("Extra books in compare : " + cbooks);
        }

    }
```